# Is it possible to dynamically change the language of a modal dialog?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, mfc, localization, internationalization

Say you have a dialog based MFC application that displays it's main dialog from the `MyWinApp::InitInstance()` function via calling `dlg.DoModal()`.

Further, this application contains localized resources (all in the project, no satellite DLLs for this test-case), that is, the `IDD_TEST_DIALOG` resource is there twice, once in English and once in German.

What I want to do now is add a button to this dialog that toggles the language of the displayed dialog between the available languages in the resources. Is this possible? (Remember: The dialog is currently displayed through the `DoModal()` function.)

When you want to change the resource language used by MFC, you call `SetThreadUILanguage` (works on WIn7 and XP) or you can also call `SetThreadPreferredUILanguages` if only targeting Win7 (Vista+). So really, if you're able to reopen the dialog, changing the language is very easy. The question for me is whether it's possible at all to somehow reload a displayed Window with different resources.

---

Note that one *could* just make sure that all strings are reloaded, that is, [somehow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16233541/321013) walk through all controls in the application and call `SetWindowText` to change the text of the windows.

However, this is counter to what a localized dialog (resource) is supposed to provide, namely *not only* translated strings, but also the necessary changes in dialog layout: Different language strings will likely be of different length, so the control have to be spaced differently. (I also could imagine that when supporting right-to-left languages or aisian scripts, the layout has to be adopted accordingly.)

Comment: It is a meaningless demo feature.  Your user has been speaking the same language as long as he's been alive.  He's not about to change it while he looks at your dialog.  If you need to test localization then just change the system locale with Control Panel.

Comment: @HansPassant: No this is not a meaningless feature. Of course this is a reduced test case, but being able to switch the UI language while an app is running can be necessary (even if (big if) it's just a "political" requirement it's still needed to sell the software). (I do agree that it *may* not necessarily be necessary to actually change the language in a modal dialog on the fly, but I figured I'd start asking at *some* point and this seemed rather a good one, as it appears to me to be one of the more complicated use cases.)

Comment: Localization is a bullet item in the feature list.  Yes, we do that.  You keep sales people happy by reminding them that they can sell to 5 billion users instead of 50 million.  And that they'll have to wait longer making the sale if they ask for meaningless bells and whistles.  That's just lost sales, making a feature that nobody actually ever uses a rather expensive luxury.   They don't understand this, you have to speak up.

Comment: @HansPassant: Localization is **not** a bullet item. We already provide our application in three different languages, and it is needed for a certain user base. I do concur that switching UI language on the fly *may* be a bullet item.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing is probably not using another dialog template but changing programmatically the texts of your dialog controls one by one by using a table that maps each control id of the dialog to a string resource.

A better solution for you would be to parse the other language's dialog template and replace the text of each control in your displayed dialog by the text found in the template and also resize and reposition the controls according to the size and position in the template dialog.

Unfortunately there is no API in Windows for parsing dialog templates, but there is a pretty [good blog entry by Raymond Chen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/03/30/10147433.aspx) that deals with dialog templates.

Pseudo code :

```
foreach (control in the other language's dialog template)
{
  string = control.GetText() ;            // Get text from dialog template's control
  CRect rect = control.GetRect() ;        // Get rectangle from dialog template's control

  CWnd *pCtrl = GetDlgItem(control.id) ;  // Get pointer to control in dialog
  pCtrl->SetWindowText(control) ;         // Set new text of control
  pCtrl->MoveWindow(rect) ;               // resize and reposition control      
}
```

Comment: I'll edit the question to explain why I think this is suboptimal.

Comment: You could actually also change the size and the position of the controls in the dialog and not only the texts. All this information can be retrieved from the dialog template. I'll edit my answer according to this.